# eigenvalues of derivative map

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

What do the eigenvalues of a derivative map from a manifold to itself describe? In particular, what are immediate consequences of it being +1? What about it being +1 at a fixed point (a point where under the original map, $p\mapsto p$?

Comment: First of all, the question makes sense only at a fixed point, so that you have a linear map from a vector space to *itself*. Essentially, the derivative linearizes the map and you're looking at the local behavior. For example, $p$ is called a Lefschetz fixed point if none of the eigenvalues is $1$. If you've studied some basic linear differential equations in $\Bbb R^n$, this is a similar context.

Comment: as background information, I'm trying to prove that there are only finitely many lefschetz fixed points when M is compact and I'm trying to understand the role of the derivative having eigenvalue 1 in the definition

Comment: Ah ... exercise from Guillemin & Pollack, eh? ... Here's a hint to get you started: If you had infinitely many, you could find a sequence that comes in to $p$ with a limiting tangent direction $v\in T_pX$.